# Catch Unfortunately app has crashed in app level in Android

Tags: android, crash

I want to know is there any option to catch the exception in application level to stop showing `Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped.` instead I want to show my custom message to the user when it crashes.

Ex: If the app crashes in any of the screen in the app I need to capture that like Crashlytics and want to show my custom message. How to do it?

Comment: Find out what Exception is being thrown and catch it.

Comment: I know but how to do it in app level?

Answer (score 1):

I personnally do it like this :

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new  Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            //DO YOUR JOB HERE
        }
    });
```

Put this in your oncreate of activity or application. The best is to save this on your application server, and advertise your user something happenned.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can I put it in my AppClass which extends Application class, if so is it handle in application level?

Comment: normally yes. Official doc says that all ui component use the same thread. So i would say yes :). The bad thing is that you lose the crashing activity context, will be harder to debug